# Is it a necessary condition for an even function to have a local extremum (for $f(x)=k,$ derivative${}=0$) at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f(x)$ be an even function ($f(-x)=f(x)$) if $f(x)$ is continuous and differentiable at $x = 0$ will it be necessary for it to have a local extremum? Or more generally, have it's derivative $=0$ at $x=0$?

I thought this as:$$f(x+h)-f(x)=f(x-h)-f(x) \\ \text{(for $x=0 , h>0$)}$$ so the derivative should also be zero. Am I correct or is there a counter example?

Comment: $f(x)=0$ is a counterexample to your title statement.

Comment: @AndrewChin But the constant function has a local max (or min) throughout.

Comment: Is that how it works?  The definition of local extremum I'm thinking about has the derivative changing signs at some $x$ value.

Comment: @AndrewChin my teacher also said exactly this :-|

Comment: @AndrewChin : That function has a weak local extremum, although not a strict local extremum, at $0. \qquad$

Comment: @AndrewChin : It is a strange definition of extremum that mentions derivatives. To say that $f$ has a strict local maximum at $c$ means that there is some open interval about $c$ such that for all $x$ in that interval $f(x)< f(c).$ Similarly for minimum. And if "weak" replaces "strict", then you just have $\text{“}{\le}\text{''}$ instead of $\text{“}{<}\text{''}.$ You see no mention of derivatives here. The relationship between derivatives and extrema is expressed in theorems, not in definitions. $\qquad$

Comment: Note that "extrema" is the plural of "extremum." Thus write: "This extremum is..." or "These extrema are..." Likewise "This maximum is..." or "These maxima are..." and "This minimum is..." and "These minima are..." I edited this question accordingly. $\qquad$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The absolute value function is an even function about which it is not true that its derivative at $0$ is $0,$ since its deriative is not defined at $0$ at all. However, all even functions $f$ that are differentiable at $0$ satisfy $f'(0)=0,$ thus:
$$
f'(0) = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(h)} h = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(-h)} h = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{-f(-h)} {-h} = -f'(0). 
$$
Since $f'(0) = -f'(0),$ we have $f'(0)=0.$

Now suppose
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2\cos(1/x) & \text{if } x\ne0, \\ 0 & \text{if } x=0. \end{cases}
$$
Then $f$ is an even function that is differentiable at $0,$ but it does not have a local extremum at $0.$

Comment: Thanks a lot, I knew piece-wise functions were stubborn enough to not follow the general rule but couldn't think of an example

Comment: @Pj30 : TYPO: I wrote $\sin$ where I should have $\cos.$ I've fixed that now.

Answer (score 1):

Derivative changes the parity (eveness/oddness) of a function. An odd function  if it is continuous vanishes at $x=0$. So  $$f(-x)=f(x) \implies  -f'(-x) =f'(x) \implies f'(0)=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)$ be a function differentiable at $x=0$.

Case 1:
$f$ is an even function.

$$ f'(x)= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}.$$

Now find $f'(-x)$.
$$f'(-x)= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(-x+h)-f(-x)}{h} $$

Since $f(-x)=f(x)$,
We conclude that $f'(-x)=-f'(x)$

$\implies$  $f'(x)$ is an odd function, hence $f'(0)=0$.

Case 2: (Not really required for your question)

$f$ is an odd function.

$$ f'(x)= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}. $$

Now find $f'(-x)$.

$$f'(-x)= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(-x+h)-f(-x)}{h} $$

Since $f(-x)=-f(x)$,

We conclude that $f'(-x)=f'(x)$

$\implies$  $f'(x)$ is an even function.

Comment: Note the typographical difference between $lim_{h\to0}$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{h\to0}.$ That is among the things I changed in editing this answer. $\qquad$

Answer (score 0):

We have $f(x)$ as an even function ⇒
$f(-x)=f(x)$

Taking derivative with respect to x.

$-f'(-x)=f'(x)$ ⇒ $f'(x)$ is odd.

Now $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x=0$

$-f'(0)=f'(0)$ ⇒ $f'(0)=0.$